# Equivalent code of selenium.refresh() in Selenium WebDriver (Selenium 2) using Java

Tags: java, refresh, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

In Selenium RC, I used the following code using Java for refresh on the browser:

```
selenium.refresh();
```

What is the equivalent code for refresh in WebDriver?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following is the equivalent code in Selenium WebDriver using Java:

```
driver.navigate().refresh();
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to refresh by using Ctrl+F5: to use the WebDriver and Actions instance as below:

```
Actions actionObject = new Actions(driver);
actionObject.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.F5).perform();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
driver.navigate().refresh();
```

Look here for example - [How To Refresh Current Web Page](http://reditblog.blogspot.in/2014/10/how-to-refresh-current-web-page.html).